# making a menu button invisible

Tags: android, button, menu

i know that has been asked alot but i'm having a problem in my app . see i added buttons in menu.xml file in menu folder and it showing up however the banner ad cover it in bottom of the app and in the upper the button is not showing up at all
here is picture of my app :[Ad covers menu view pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi9if.jpg) also this
[without ads pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46QwY.jpg) . plus i want to enlarge share & rate buttons size...
here is how i want menu button to be like : [menu button pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82c6P.jpg) [menu pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cdoG.png)

here is my menu xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/privacy"
        android:title="@string/privacy_policy"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:textSize="150sp"
        android:layout_height="150sp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Disclaimer"
        android:title="@string/disclaimer"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:textSize="150sp"
        android:layout_height="150sp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/More"
        android:title="@string/more_apps"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:textSize="150sp"
        android:layout_height="150sp" />
</menu>
```

here is my java activity code :

```
import com.xxx.xxx.database.DataBaseHelper;
import com.xxx.xxx.R;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    InterstitialAd  mInterstitialAd;
    AdRequest adRequest;
    Button start;
    ProgressBar progressBar ;
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        DataBaseHelper.setmDatabase(this);
        AppRater.setAPP_PNAME(this);



        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(SettingsApp.Interstitial);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListViewsItems.class);
                //intent.putExtra("id",""+itemClicked.getDirection());
                //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())  mInterstitialAd.show();
                finish();
                //else Toast.makeText(Start.this, "nonLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.privacy:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://xxx.xxx")));
                return true;
            case R.id.Disclaimer:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://xxx.xxx")));
                return true;
            case R.id.More:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=" + "xxx")));// ADD YOUR DEVELOPER NAME HERE USE + FOR SPACE
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
         mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the toolbar in your activity.

Try adding it to the xml of your activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            ... />
```

And then setting it as the toolbar:

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
```

Comment: hey man thanks for your answer however when i add the code you give me "setSupportActionBar(findViewById(toolbar))" in my main activity java 
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(toolbar));  i get this "error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar"

Comment: also i'm not sure if you mean add to menu.xml or main activity.xml this code ( so i added in both of them ) :                  
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />http://www.crystalinks.com/chakras.html

Comment: It actually should said setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))